# phpuml command not found

Tags: php, xslt, pear, umbrello

I m trying to set up phpuml to generate xmi files which I intent to import using umbrello.
I have managed to get PHP_UML installed using XSL alpha package which is a dependency for PHP_UML.

Here is the output of the list command

```
vihaan@cd:~$ pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package             Version State
Archive_Tar         1.3.11  stable
Console_CommandLine 1.2.0   stable
Console_Getopt      1.3.1   stable
PEAR                1.9.4   stable
PHP_UML             1.6.1   stable
Structures_Graph    1.0.4   stable
XML_Util            1.2.1   stable
XML_XSLT_Wrapper    0.2.2   alpha
```

It seems like PHP_UML is installed but on trying to execute the phpuml command I get

```
vihaan@cd:~$ phpuml
phpuml: command not found
```

I cant figure out whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see where the phpuml script for installed to, use the command

```
$ pear list php_uml | grep phpuml
```

Comment: thanks , it helped me solve the problem. The include path was coming from a different php.ini.